# How do I delete a line that contains a specific string at a specific location using sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed, command

I want to find and delete all lines that have a specific string, with a specific length, at a specific location.

One line in my data set looks something like this:

```
STRING   1234567 1234567 7654321 6543217 5432176
```

Notes:

- Entries have field widths of 8
- Identification numbers can be repeated in the same line
- Identification numbers can be repeated on a different line, but at a different location - these lines should not be deleted

In this example, I want to find lines containing "1234567" located at column 17 and spanning to column 24 (i.e. the third field) and delete them. How can I do this with sed or awk?

I have used the following, but it deletes lines that I want to keep:

```
sed -i '/1234567/d' ./file_name.dat
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i '/^.\{17\}1234567/d' ./file_name.dat
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `.{17}` - any 17 chars
- `1234567` - a substring.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/PjAb9r):

```
s="STRING   1234567 1234567 7654321 6543217 5432176
STRING   1234567 5534567 7654321 6543217 5432176"
sed '/^.\{17\}1234567/d' <<< "$s"
# => STRING   1234567 5534567 7654321 6543217 5432176
```

Comment: Op wants `s` instead of `d`

Comment: @Kent See *"I want to find and delete all lines that have a specific string, with a specific length, at a specific location."*. Let OP decide which solution works best

Comment: I read `I have used the following, but it deletes lines that I want to keep:` ... :D perhaps you are right, he probably meant the matches at other locations.

Answer (score 0):

with `awk`, print lines except the substring match.

```
$ awk 'substr($0,17,7)=="1234567"{next}1' file > output_file
```

or perhaps inverse logic is easier

```
$ awk 'substr($0,17,7)!="1234567"' file > output_file
```